# Orthogonal Polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

Let $\{P_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ a family of polynomials in $[a,b]$ where $n$ is the degree of $P_n$. Suppose they are orthogonal with respect to a positive wight function $\rho$. Show that $P_n$ has $n$ zeros in $[a,b]$.

From the data we have that for any $n,m$, it is true that:

$$\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} P_n(x)P_m(x)\rho (x) = 0$$

How should I proceed for the desired result?

Comment: Also zeros of two consecutive orthogonal polynomials interlace?

Answer (score 4):

Presumably $P_0$ is a nonzero constant and $a<b$. You may first prove that $P_n(x)$ is orthogonal to all arbitrary polynomials with lower degrees. Now, as $\int_a^b P_n(x)1\rho(x)=0$, $P_n$ must have a zero $c\in[a,b]$. Let $P_n(x)=(x-c)q_{n-1}(x)$. Since $P_n$ is orthogonal to all polynomials with lower degree, we have, in particular, $\int_a^b P_n(x)(x-c)\rho(x)=0$, i.e. $\int_a^b q_{n-1}(x)(x-c)^2\rho(x)=0$. So $q_{n-1}$ must have a zero in $[a,b]$ and you may proceed recursively.

Comment: Why $\int_a^b q_{n-1}(x)(x-c)^2 \rho(x)=0 => q_{n-1}$ must have a zero in  $[a,b]$ is true? In the first case we can use the mean value theorem for integrals, but in this case we can't because  $q_{n-1}(x)(x-c)^2 = 0$ for $x = c \in [a, b]$

Comment: I just noticed that if $q_{n-1}$ doesn't have a zero in $[a,b]$, then the integral should be either strictly positive or strictly negative.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, wlog. we can assume that the constant polynomial is $P_0(x)=1$.

Intuitively it can go like this:

We need $\langle P_1,P_0\rangle=0$, so $P_1$ *cannot* be only positive (or only negative) all over $[a,b]$.

For $P_2$, consider both $\langle P_2,P_0\rangle=0$ and $\langle P_2,P_1\rangle=0$. The first one tells you (just as before) that $P_2$ must also change sign at least once, and if you spell out the other one, regarding possible signs, and let's say $P_1$'s root is $x_1$, it will lead that $P_2$ must change sign in both $(a,x_1)$ and $(x_1,b)$.

I hope it gets the picture..